# IdentityServer IIS windows authentication problem when changing hostName

Tags: iis, identityserver4, windows-authentication

I have IdentityServer (.net core 2.0) on IIS configured to work with Windows Authentication and everything works fine when the hostname on that application is set to the name of the server but when I am trying to change the binding to a different name then I cannot log in with Windows (401 Unauthorized). DNS is configured to work with both names same as the SSL certificate.

Any ideas why different hostname causes problems with IdentityServer while using Windows auth?

Comment: what is your specific operation 'change the binding to a different name '?

Comment: RMB on IdentityServer application in IIS -> Edit bindings -> host name (https)